# Overide rails model_class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a basic class `User` with a `type string` column, two type of users User and SuperAdmin, SuperAdmin model inherits from user.

class User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  def superadmin?
    type == 'superadmin'
  end
```

end

```
class SuperAdmin < User
end
```

The `model_class` method returns `User class`, is it possible to overide that behavior and return SuperAdmin instead?

Comment: What do you need that for? Can you use method `class`?

Comment: You should probably use Modules. For example Admin::User which will be in the admin Module, and User that will be a different thing. But it's a bit confusing, I think it would be better to use different naming for this and just stick to specifying proper associations.

Comment: A better idea altogether might be to not have different user classes and instead add a role system for example with Rolify.